# Expresión regular que solo permita los valores 10 y 22

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework

necesito una expresión regular que solo permita el ingreso del número "22" o el número "10".
Es para ponerla en una propiedad para utilizar con entity framework.

```
[RegularExpression(Aqui va la expresion)]
    [Display(Name = "% IVA")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error, el IVA es un campo requerido")]
```

No se bien como sería. 
Puede resultar una estupidez, pero no encuentro la solución.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: `"22|10"` creo que serviría

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(10|20)$
```

Explicación:

`^` Desde el principio de la cadena

`()` Definir un grupo

`|` "Or" hará match con cualquiera de los items del grupo

`$` Hasta el final de la cadena

Comment: Muchas gracias!!